# How to view actual Event Grid message in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights, azure-eventgrid

I have an Event Grid subscribed to an Azure Storage Account. Its set to trigger whenever a blob of certain file extension is uploaded and also when a certain upload api is used.

These filters are defined in Event Grid Advanced Filters. All works great.

Sometimes the Filters kick in and the Event Grid does not fire (which is fine), but how do I see which filter stopped the Event Grid from firing?

**Example:**

- Here it shows (I think?) that the Event Grid did not fire due to "Advanced Filter Evaluation":
  [image]

**Where do I view the actual text logging showing which filter kicked in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Advanced Filter Evaluations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/metrics) metric is the Total advanced filters evaluated across event subscriptions for the topic. As the filter condition evaluation doesn't match with the input event then the events will be dropped and there is no way to figure out using metrics or any other logs that are available at your end.

Alternatively, you can create one more event grid subscription on the same storage account that has no filter condition that will help you to compare the event that you have not received with the advanced filter.

Comment: Any insights on this [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117455/how-to-troubleshoot-ghost-azure-function-events)? This is why I need to view **all** EventGrid messages. Need transparency, especially for critical applications where auditing is required.

Comment: What is the actual table in Log Analytics to query to see EventGrid messages? I have a Diagnostic Setting on the System Topic. This results in an `AegDeliveryFailureLogs` table in Log Analytics but this doesn't show all events (Successful, AdvancedFilterApplied, etc.).

Comment: It  does not seem like you answer question at all on how to view the event grid message https://stackoverflow.com/users/13796136/mayankbargali